# natbib, et al by more than one author

Tags: bibtex, natbib, author-number

I've got some problems with my bibliography style

Code:

```
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage[english,ngerman{babel}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Einleitung}

Text..... \citep{Marley2009}


\bibliography{literatur} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}


@ARTICLE{Marley2009,
author = {Marley and Smith},
title = {Einsatz von Pulveraktivkohle zur Elimination von Mikroverunreinigungen
aus dem Abwasser},
journal = {blabla},
year = {2009},
owner = {bobmarley},
timestamp = {2012.10.31}
}
```

I'm getting then

> [Marley and Smith2009]

what I want is

> [Marley et al 2009], et al

by more than one authors.

Any idea how get that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Which document class do you use? Please complete your given code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1):

The `plainnat` BibTeX style abbreviates authors when there are 3 or more authors. You have to change the BibTeX style. A style that does that is `chicago`, or you can create you own BibTeX style with `custom-bib`. For option use a terminal window (command line) and run `latex makebst` and then follow the prompt.

Comment: @Guido Damn I missed that, sorry for that.